# Paired string delimiters?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, string, syntax-table

[Red](http://www.red-lang.org/) and [Rebol](http://www.rebol.com/docs/core23/rebolcore-3.html#section-2.6) have multiline strings that start with `{` and end with `}`. Reading through Elisp docs I don't see any simple way to define this in the syntax table. The string quotes class matches the same character only and the generic string delimiters class wouldn't work correctly either.

Comment: What are you looking to do? [Smartparens](https://github.com/Fuco1/smartparens) will help with insertion/deletion/navigation, but it looks like you're also concerned with other behavior.

Comment: The question was for making a major mode that correctly defines this as a string through the syntax table. As I looked through other language implementations I think the only option is to scan the text and use the generic string delimiter syntax class via the `syntax-table` `text-property` of the character.

Comment: Did you find any emacs modes implementing paired string delimiters in your research @xificurC?

Comment: @Winny I sure did, just didn't include in the comments. The first one that comes to mind is lua - https://github.com/immerrr/lua-mode/blob/d2ff3045b9694293a302fa60d7bd5d97f2673156/lua-mode.el#L843